# How to prove $f_{X+b}(x) = f_{X}(x-b)$?

Tags: probability-distributions

In the probability course on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2M4LNSeIn4&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60hI9ATjSFgLZpbNJ7myAg6&index=123) at 6:23, the professor said that:

$$f_{X+b}(x) = f_{X}(x-b)$$

Why is this the case? Could someone offer a proof?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the CDF of $X + b$:

$$ F_{X+b}(x) = \Pr\{X + b \leq x\} = \Pr\{X \leq x - b\} = F_X(x - b)$$

where $F_{X+b}, F_X$ are the CDF of $X+b$ and $X$ respectively. Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$, we have

$$ \begin{align} \frac {\partial} {\partial x} F_{X+b}(x) 
&= \frac {\partial} {\partial x} F_X(x - b) \\ 
\Rightarrow f_{X+b}(x) &= \frac {\partial} {\partial (x - b)}F_X(x - b) \times \frac {\partial (x - b)} {\partial x} \\
&= f_X(x-b)\end{align}$$

where it is well-known that differentiating the CDF will obtain the corresponding pdf

Comment: Hi BGM, the chain rule part where $F_{x}(x-b)$ differentiated by x seems to be a typo of differentiated by (x-b)? But thanks a lot!